# Insert data in relationship table without identity_insert ON

Tags: sql-server, identity-insert

I am having a scenario where I have to insert some master data into the table with script, so that we can this script on production server while deployment.

My tables are

```
Category
 --Id (PK, Identity)
 --Name

CategoryType
  --Id (PK, Identity)
  --Name
  --CategoryID (FK)
```

Now I have some row data in excel for category and categorytype.
I have to generate the data script (bunch of insert statement).

### What I did

```
Start with  identity_insert ON 
insert statement for Category table
Insert statement for CategoryType table with respect of category PK
end  identity_insert Off
```

I just want to know Is there any way I can avoid identity_insert ON/OFF thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this is what you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @inserted table ( id int ) --assuming ID is int

INSERT INTO Category ( Name )
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @inserted
VALUES( 'MyCategory Name' )

INSERT INTO CategoryType( Name, CategoryID )
SELECT id, 'MyCategoryTypeName'
FROM @inserted
```

Hope it helps
Best Regards,
 
Iordan